# Express API server is blocking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I am testing my API server. I wanted to simulate what if 1000 users called the same route at the same time. So to test that, I made the following:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let all = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const a = fetch(`http://localhost:3001/custom/a`).then(res => res.json())
        all.push(a)
    }

    all = await Promise.all(all);
    res.json('finished')
})
```

And the route I am testing is this one:

```
router.get('/a', async (req, res) => {
    const video = await Video.find().limit(1).exec();
    res.json(video)
})
```

So when I am hitting route manually (thru postman or browser), 1 request at the time, the response times are about 60ms.

But when I initiate 1000 routes, each response is like waiting for previous to finish. Take a look at this log at [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/n5AZRbfV)

So I wanna know, what I did wrong? Who here is blocking? Is it mongoose and database (I tried increasing pool size to 1000, still the same), or did I misunderstood how Node is working?

Comment: comment mongoose query and return the simple string, still the same result?

Comment: No, each response is about the same, it's not going in ascending order like with mongoose. So it is database problem.

Comment: I recommend using JMeter with your API to load testing!

Comment: are you reading the same Video file each time? @Wolfdog

Comment: Not really, that is just for demonstration purpose. Any route that works with db has this kinda problem. Can any of you guys check your apis, can u see response times on route working with db when u hit it with the /test code above?